# Общение между доменами в mailManager (PHP, mail)

Tags: email, php

У меня этот хостинг ([ссылка](http://bit.ly/hosting2012)), там есть ограничение на количество `mail()` - 200 в час, все что больше, не высылается. На том тарифе 8 сайтов. Я делаю менеджер рассылок, который на одном из доменов будет накапливать "стек" писем в базу данных, и когда пройдет 1 час после последней отправки писем, будет слать 200 писем, удалять их из базы и обновлять время последней отправки писем. Вызываться менеджер будет по cron или по входу пользователей/ботов на сайт.

Вопроса три всего.

1. Как мне передавать письмо с одного домена на домен, где установлен этот менеджер? Я пока думаю методом `POST`, `CURL`, `file_get_contents`. Есть недостаток - не хочу пинговать свой же домен, если добавляю письма менеджеру с этого же домена (задержка, перерасход ресурсов хостинга)?
2. Как обеспечить защиту, чтобы, например, вы не добавили в мой менеджер свои письма?
3. Как добавить 500 писем, у меня подписчиков именно сколько? Если каждого отдельно, то это выйдет на долго, да и 500 запросов к серверу (это если AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

сделайте базу для рассылки. добавляете что отослать - кому отослать - с какого обратного адреса. записываете в базу (так как все сайты на одном хосте то каждый сможет работать с одной базой.) затем во время рассылки берете из базы посылаете и если норм отослалось стираете в базе(берете по одному сверху). если нет возможности доступа к базе со всех сайтов то делаете на одном скрипт и в него передаете данные POST запросом. чтобы никто чужой не юзал скрипт просто сделайте ключ типа пароля который будет передаваться. но по идее одна база будет на хосте доступна для всех.

Comment: Собственно всё кроме общей базы я уже придумал точно так как вы предлагаете. Не хочется нарушать архитектуру CodeIgniter - в том плане, что я не знаю как устанавливать соединение к другой базе (а низкоуровневый доступ не выход). Хотя это идея. Поищу вот, когда вынесу мусор и  поем...

Comment: ну вам надо просто посмотреть данные для любой базы (лучше создать новую но если нет возможности то любую и префикс на таблицу поставить например mail_). а соединение стандартное для одного хостинга<pre>mysql_connect( $gbHost, $gbUser, $gbPass ) or die( "невозможно подключиться к базе" );
  mysql_select_db( $gbName );
  mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
</pre>